# What is $K_1(\mathrm{Var}_\Bbbk)$?

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, motives, grothendieck-rings

Ok, this is a very naive question, and not seriously motivated. But I was just wondering: did anybody define any (interesting) higher K-theory Grothendieck group of varieties $K_n(\mathrm{Var}_{\Bbbk})$ generalizing the usual Grothendieck ring $K_0(\mathrm{Var}_\Bbbk)$?

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't realize that there was already an essentially identical question.